# document onclick with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, onclick

I got somthing like this on React?

```
 $(document).on("click", function (e) { ... }
```

Or is mandatory to use onClick on all components?

Comment: Are you getting error when running this code?

Comment: I don't see a reason to use jQuery with React. We can simply use `onClick` for things like this. Is there any reason for you to use jQuery here?

Answer (score 2):

**It is not a good practice and You should try and avoid jQuery in ReactJS, But:**

You can have that, but in order to do that you need to add your code in the right life cycle hook
for example, you can do this

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

useEffect(() => {
    function onClickHanlder (e) { ... }
    $(document).on("click", onClickHanlder)

    // to prevent leak memory unsubscribe from event on unmount
    return () => {
        $(document).off("click")
    }
},[]);
```

In a class component you can add your code in **componentDidMount**

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {  

  useEffect(() => {
    initCustomScripts();
 }, [])

 const initCustomScripts = () => {
  document.getElementById('custom-button').addEventListener('click', function(){
        //code here
        alert('custom-button clicked');
  })
}

 return (
    <div>
        <button id="custom-button">Custom button</button>
    </div>
);

  
}
export default App;
```